# How to only call onPostExecute when method in doinbackground is finished?

Tags: java, android, service, android-asynctask

**I call this in an onClickListener**

```
AsyncTaskBindService asyncTaskBindService = new AsyncTaskBindService(position, songList);

asyncTaskBindService.execute();
```

**Asynctask class**

```
public class AsyncTaskBindService extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    private int songIndex;
    private ArrayList<Song> songList;

    public AsyncTaskBindService(int songIndex, ArrayList<Song> songList){
        this.songIndex = songIndex;
        this.songList = songList;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            if (getActivity() != null && !Main.mServiceIsBound) {
                Main.bindMusicService(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                Log.i(TAG,"binding service!");
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG,"error binding Service!");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        if (getActivity() != null && Main.mServiceIsBound) {
            Main.mediaPlayerService.startActionPlay(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), songList, songIndex);
            Log.i(TAG,"start song!");
        }
    }
```

**Problem is in my doInBackground:**

This line:

```
Main.bindMusicService(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

This method calls `bindService` in another class which then returns an instance to my Service.

But the problem is that Asynctask finished way to fast and when `onPostExecute` gets called it returns an NPE because `mediaPlayerService` is still null because `onServiceConnected` is slower than my Asynctask.

How to solve this?

Now i have to click a song 2 times before it starts playing.

**EDIT**

First i tried this, but my second if never gets called because it takes some time before onServiceConnected() is finished.

How can i immediately execute my second method if bindService is finished and my service is bound?

**onClick Song**

```
if (!Main.mServiceIsBound && getActivity() != null) {
        Main.bindMusicService(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        Log.i(TAG,"Service is not bound yet!, binding Service...");
    }
    if (getActivity()!= null && Main.mServiceIsBound) {
        Main.mediaPlayerService.startActionPlay(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), songList, position);
    }
```

**Main class**

```
/**This establishes the connection to the MediaPlayerService. */
public static ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        MediaPlayerService.MusicBinder binder = (MediaPlayerService.MusicBinder)service;
        mediaPlayerService = binder.getService();
        mServiceIsBound = true;
        Log.i("Main","MediaPlayerService Connected!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mServiceIsBound = false;
        Log.i("Main","MediaPlayerService Disconnected!");
    }
};

public static void bindMusicService(Context c){
    /*mediaPlayerServiceIntent binds our connection to the MediaPlayerService. */
    try{
    mediaPlayerServiceIntent = new Intent(c, MediaPlayerService.class);
    c.bindService(mediaPlayerServiceIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Main", "Service is not bound!");
    }
    Log.i("Main","Service is bound!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `AsyncTask`s `doInBackGround` run asynchronously, yet when you bind a component to a `Service`  by using `bindService` that also runs asynchronously causing `Main.bindMusicService` to return immediately.

An `AsyncTask` is not a good candidate for this sort of work. You should be binding to a service in the **main thread** (UI thread) and listen for the `onServiceConnected` callback of the `ServiceConnection` object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but then i still have the problem i have to tap a song 2 times, how can i check if my service is bound, if not then call bindService and immediately after my service is connected call Main.mediaPlayerService.startActionPlay();

Comment: No, you need to implement `ServiceConnection` and wait for `onServiceConnected` to be called...that's when you know your service has been bound to the activity. What happens in the click listener depends on your application flow...you can bind to the service when the user clicks on the song or bind to the service from the activity `onStart` but making sure the songs are not clickable before the service is connected

Comment: Yes that's what Main.bindMusicService(getActivity().getApplicationContext()); does, it calls bindservice in another class which then calls onServiceConnected, but how can i immediately start my song without having to press it twice?

Comment: What i want to achieve is that when i click on a song it starts playing, but makes sure my service is bound, if not bound then call my bindservice method and immediately after onServiceConnected is finished i call my second method ( play song) check my edit

Comment: this `Main.mediaPlayerService.startActionPlay(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), songList, songIndex);` whatever that does should probably be called `onServiceConnected`.  As I mentioned, `bindService` runs asynchronously and an `AsyncTask` won't work here